# Synchronize two input fields , without building an endless loop?

Tags: swt, synchronization, textfield, infinite-loop

I have two input fields which i would like to sync with each other.
Unfortunately, when I add a ChangeListener to each of the TextFields they will trigger each other,
and so create an andless loop.

Ofcourse I could unregister the Listeners, on every change and them put them back,
but is there any Java native approach?

Maybe something with bindings?

Answer (score 1):

From general reasoning (i.e. not knowing swt or java): you can add a boolean flag (probably your class member) `m_enteredChangeListener`, temporary setting it to true in *one* of your handlers (not both), making the same handler do nothing if it's reentered recursively.

Comment: but who can guarantee, that the listener will be tiggered BEFORE I have released teh log. Especially if I will use multithreading later.

Comment: Aren't you limited to one GUI thread for GUI event handlers? (and if "teh log" refers to "the lock": I recommend no lock, just a bare boolean flag -- preventing a single function from reentering itself, so it won't react on text changes causing by itself reacting on text changes).